# Sleeping position with Hepatitis A

Tags: sleep, liver, position

My girlfriend just got discharged from the hospital after being treating for Hepatitis A for a week. Now she is being asked to take care regarding the food she eats and not exert pressure on liver.

Her mom keeps asking her to sleep straight and not the way usually she sleeps. She's unable to fall asleep straight, so we wanted to know that if sleeping is actually a concern an are there specific ways you should lie down during Hepatitis?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Health.SE. This seems like it could be a good question, but you are asking two questions. One about sleeping position, and one about physical activity. Could you please specify just one question? (I'm assuming you want the sleeping position instead of physical activity) Thanks :)

Comment: To me, sleeping position doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @michaelpri My question is mainly about Sleeping Position. The query about physical activity is secondary, for which I'll ask another question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might hazard a guess that "don't put pressure on your liver" means don't take medications that might tax the liver, or drink alcohol, etc. I don't *think* they meant "don't squeeze the liver."

However, if they did mean that, it would be my recommendation that she sleep in the left lateral decubitus position.

[image]

Since the liver is on the right side, lying on her left side with the head of the bed slightly elevated will exert the least amount of pressure on the liver. Probably the next best thing would be on her back with the head of the bed slighty elevated.

I did find one paper addressing the position of the body in the treatment of various illnesses, calling the role of position in treatment "postural medicine". Much of this is common sense (that is, experience has taught us as much) but some of it is new to me.

[The role of body position and gravity in the symptoms and treatment of various medical diseases](http://www.medicinabiomolecular.com.br/biblioteca/pdfs/Doencas/do-1170.pdf).